# Custom keyboard layout is reset to default after standby or reboot

Tags: x11, keyboard, xfce, keyboard-layout

I designed a keyboard layout for myself, after I run `xmodmap` it works OK, but after standby or reboot, the layout turn back to qwerty.

How can I set it as default? My OS is Debian Wheezy with XFCE4.

Comment: I have the same problem, debian jessie with xfce4.

Answer (score 8):

Check out this archlinux forum thread [Xmodmap Reset after Suspend to RAM](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=88369). There are several examples in the thread that'll get you started and show you how to setup a hook which will get triggered via the power management subsystem that will run your `xmodmap` setup each time you come out of suspend.

Something like the following script, saved as `/etc/pm/sleep.d/11suspend` (change the `me` in  `/bin/su - me` to your actual username):

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    hibernate)
        echo "Hey guy, we are going to suspend to disk!"
        ;;
    suspend)
        echo "Oh, this time we're doing a suspend to RAM. Cool!"
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        echo "oh, suspend is over, we are in $1 phase..."
            # Set Display #
    DISPLAY=:0.0 ; export DISPLAY
    /bin/su - me -c "sleep 3; /usr/bin/xmodmap /home/me/.xmodmaprc" &
        ;;
    *)  echo "somebody is calling me totally wrong."
        ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 3):

Premilinary note: you shouldn't use the obsolete `xmodmap` command, but XKB (`xkbcomp`).

Then you can change the settings from your `~/.xsession` script. Personally I have:

```
setxkbmap -types local -print | \
  sed -e '/xkb_symbols/s/"[[:space:]]/+local&/' > $HOME/.xkb/keymap/custom
xkbcomp -w0 -I$HOME/.xkb -R$HOME/.xkb keymap/custom $DISPLAY
```

in my `~/.xsession` file, and my XKB settings are put in `~/.xkb/symbols/local` and `~/.xkb/types/local` files. This will change the settings after each X login.

Unfortunately these settings are [lost after suspend/resume](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71168). There's a workaround: save them and restore them via pm-utils with a script in the `/etc/pm/sleep.d` directory; you may need

```
xhost +si:localuser:root
```

in your `~/.xsession` script since root doesn't have your xauth information. I have given an example (for XKB): https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=633849#92

Comment: `~/.xsession` is not being called after resume here. do you know why?

Comment: @brauliobo `~/.xsession` is never executed after resume, just when the X session starts. You need to do `xhost +si:localuser:root` only at this time.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I had no idea there was a newer method than `xmodmap` to load custom keymaps. It seems to work much better too. In my case (XUbuntu 18.04) it seems to survive suspend/resume too.